# How django cached template loader work?

Tags: python, django, templates, caching, loader

I want to enable the cached loader.
I dont understand how django save the template files- according to the docs, a template is "cached" the first time the is's encountered.
But is there's a way to define a python variable for the entire django application? Assuming I havent configured any cache like memcached.  The only option I know is to define a django setting, but these variables are read-only..
So how and where django store cached template without the use of external cache application or database?

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/cache/

Comment: @allcaps django cached loader do not use standard dj cache mechanism. Precompiled templates are stored in dict inside memory. See source https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/template/loaders/cached.py